# enable/disable MACRO using __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c++, c

Consider this code:

```
// Macros to support option testing
#define _CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_false 0
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_true  1
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_0     0
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_1     1
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_      1
#define ENABLED(b) _CAT(SWITCH_ENABLED_, b)
```

I copy from the Marlin, a 3Dprinter Firmware.I dont not how it work to support opthin testing. it is used as follows in Marlin:

```
#if ENABLED(USE_WATCHDOG)
  #include "watchdog.h"
#endif
```

Obviously the function of this MACRO，ENABLED(USE_WATCHDOG)，is to determine whether USE_WATCHDOG is defined.
  For example, I really defined USE_WATCHDOG, I substitute it into ENABLED(b), the expansion is _CAT(SWITCH_ENABLED_, USE_WATCHDOG). _CAT will stitch SWITCH_ENABLED_, USE_WATCHDOG into
SWITCH_ENABLED_USE_WATCHDOG, but this macro doesn't exist. Why is the SWITCH_ENABLED_USE_WATCHDOG equivalent to 1 and finally include"watchdog.h"?

Comment: Can't reproduce https://wandbox.org/permlink/GiTSTaRXrYy6X6nL Either `SWITCH_ENABLED_USE_WATCHDOG` actually *is* defined somewhere or you accidentally include `watchdog.h` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously the function of this MACRO，ENABLED(USE_WATCHDOG)，is to determine whether USE_WATCHDOG is defined.

Not exactly.  The purpose is to determine whether it is defined *to `1` or `true`* or nothing on one hand or to `0` or `false`, or is not defined, on the other. Absent other support (not shown) for other values, if it is defined then its value must be one of those values for compilation to succeed.

> For example, I really defined USE_WATCHDOG, I substitute it into ENABLED(b), the expansion is _CAT(SWITCH_ENABLED_, USE_WATCHDOG).

Except where used as the operand of the `#` or `##` preprocessing operator, the arguments to a macro are fully expanded before they are substituted into the macro's replacement text.  Therefore, the expansion of `ENABLED(USE_WATCHDOG)` depends on the definition, if any, of `USE_WATCHDOG`.  For example if it is defined to `true`:

```
#define USE_WATCHDOG true
```

then `ENABLED(USE_WATCHDOG)` expands to

```
_CAT(SWITCH_ENABLED_, true)
```

, which is then subject to being rescanned for additional macro substitutions.

> _CAT will stitch SWITCH_ENABLED_, USE_WATCHDOG into SWITCH_ENABLED_USE_WATCHDOG, but this macro doesn't exist.

You've already gone off the rails here.  What actually happens, with `USE_WATCHDOG` defined as above, is that at this stage `_CAT(SWITCH_ENABLED_, true)` is expanded to

```
SWITCH_ENABLED_true
```

(even if `true` is itself defined as a macro), which is again subject to rescan for additional macro substitutions.
One more round of macro substitution finally reduces this to simply

```
1
```

> Why is the SWITCH_ENABLED_USE_WATCHDOG equivalent to 1 and finally include"watchdog.h"?

In the code presented, it isn't, but that's unimportant (see above).

Note especially that the `_CAT` macro is key to making all this work.  You need a double layer of macro expansion in order to get `USE_WATCHDOG` expanded before the result is pasted to `SWITCH_ENABLED_`, and that seems to be your point of misunderstanding.

Comment: thanks for attention, John. I still feel puzzled. you have said USE_WATCHDOG must be 1 or 0(true or false).but i just "#define USE_WATCHDOG ". USE_WATCHDOG  didn't have value, it still works.Actually, in Marlin Firmware code, it also doing like this:if I wanna use watchdog,"#define USE_WATCHDOG " in configure.h.  if  USE_WATCHDOG have no value, why can ENABLED(USE_WATCHDOG) expand to _CAT(SWITCH_ENABLED_, true) or anything that will finally equivalent to 1?

Comment: Look again, @nate_lee.  I say `USE_WATCHDOG` must be defined to `1` or `true` *or nothing* on the one hand.  If you define it without specifying a value, then it is defined to nothing (which is different from not being defined at all).  In this case, the second round of macro expansion results in `SWITCH_ENABLED_`, which then also expands to 1 on the next pass.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Notice these are all defaults for enabling a switch:

```
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_true  1
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_1     1
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_      1
```

Yes, that last one will enable a switch if no switch macro or override exists.

So, you can enable `USE_WATCHDOG` in the following ways:

1. Override `USE_WATCHDOG` (expands to `ENABLED(true)`)

   ```
   #define USE_WATCHDOG true
   ```
2. Override `USE_WATCHDOG` (expands to `ENABLED(1)`)

   ```
   #define USE_WATCHDOG 1
   ```
3. Enable only the switch

   ```
   #undef USE_WATCHDOG
   #define SWITCH_ENABLED_USE_WATCHDOG 1
   ```
4. Have no definitions

   ```
   #undef USE_WATCHDOG
   #undef SWITCH_ENABLED_USE_WATCHDOG
   ```

If none of these apply to you, it's possible that one of them is defined in a header you didn't know about, or outside of the code (e.g. project settings, Makefile, etc, or a pre-include file).